# useSpring breaks scroll tied animation Framer Motion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, framer-motion

I've set up a scroll animation on an element that's tied to the scroll progress of it's parent container with Framer Motion:

```
const Test = ({ children }: Props) => {

    const scrollRef = useRef(null);

    const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
        target: scrollRef,
    });

    const x = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.2], ["100%", "0%"]);

    return (
        <Container ref={scrollRef}>
            <Sticky style={{ x }}>{children}</Sticky>
        </Container>
    );
};
```

The above works as expected until I bring `useSpring()` into the mix:

```
    const x = useSpring(useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.2], ["100%", "0%"]), {
        stiffness: 100,
        damping: 30,
        restDelta: 0.001,
    });
```

After some error testing I discovered that the percentage values:`["100%", "0%"]` when combined with `useScroll()` seem to be the culprit. The animation behaves as expected if I swap them out with just numbers (`[100, 0]`).

I've tried separating out `useScroll()` and `useTransform()` like so:

```
    const xPos = useTransform(scrollYProgress, [0, 0.2], ["100%", "0%"])

    const x = useSpring(xPos, {
        stiffness: 100,
        damping: 30,
        restDelta: 0.001,
    });
```

but this doesn't work either.

Any idea how I can get this working with percentage values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this same problem and finally have a solution to this

```
 const { scrollYProgress } = useScroll({
    target: scrollRef,
});

 const temporaryx = useSpring(scrollYProgress, {
    stiffness: 100,
    damping: 30,
    restDelta: 0.001,
  });

let x = useTransform(temporaryx, [0, 0.2], ["100%", "0%"])
```

So basically you use the useSpring function on the scrollYprogress motion value, this way the spring animation should be applied, I hope this help

Comment: Ah, fantastic! Kudos for posting here after finding the solution.